# Converting char to integer in INSERT using IIF and SIMILAR TO

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I am using in insert statement to convert BDE table (source) to a Firebird table (destination) using IB Datapump. So the INSERT statement is fed by source table values via parameters. One of the source field parameters is `alphanum (SOURCECHAR10 char(10)`, holds mostly integers and needs to be converted to integer in the (integer type) destination column `NEWINTFLD`. If `SOURCECHAR10` is not numeric, I want to assign 0 to `NEWINTFLD`.

I use `IIF` and `SIMILAR` to to test whether the string is numeric, and assign 0 if not numeric as follows:

```
INSERT INTO "DEST_TABLE" (......,  "NEWINTFLD",.....)          
VALUES(..., IIF( :"SOURCECHAR10" SIMILAR TO '[[:DIGIT:]]*', :"SOURCECHAR10", 0),..)
```

For every non numeric string however, I still get conversion errors `(DSQL error code = -303)`.

I tested with only constants in the `IIF` result fields like `SOURCECHAR10" SIMILAR TO '[[:DIGIT:]]*', 1, 0)` and that works fine so somehow the :`SOURCECHAR10` in the true result field of the `IIF` generates the error.
Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: If I read this correctly, you're only testing that the values start with a digit.  Do you have values that start with a digit but have a non-digit value later on?

Comment: yes, could be. But afaik [[:DIGIT:]]* means 'any number of digits' if I look in http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-similar-to.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your query is executed, the parser will notice that second use of `:"SOURCECHAR10"` is used in a place where an integer is expected. Therefor it will always convert the contents of :SOURCECHAR10 into an integer for that position, even though it is not used if the string is non-integer.

In reality Firebird does not use `:"SOURCECHAR10"` as parameters, but your connection library will convert it to two separate parameter placeholders `?` and the type of the second placeholder will be INTEGER. So the conversion happens before the actual query is executed.

The solution is probably (I didn't test it, might contain syntax errors) to use something like (**NOTE**: see second example for correct solution):

```
CASE 
   WHEN :"SOURCECHAR10" SIMILAR TO '[[:DIGIT:]]*' 
      THEN CAST(:"SOURCECHAR10" AS INTEGER) 
   ELSE 0 
END
```

*This doesn't work as this is interpreted as a cast of the parameter itself, see [CAST() item 'Casting input fields'](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-cast.html)*

If this does not work, you could also attempt to add an explicit cast to VARCHAR around `:"SOURCECHAR10"` to make sure the parameter is correctly identified as being VARCHAR:

```
CASE 
   WHEN :"SOURCECHAR10" SIMILAR TO '[[:DIGIT:]]*' 
      THEN CAST(CAST(:"SOURCECHAR10" AS VARCHAR(10) AS INTEGER) 
   ELSE 0 
END
```

*Here the inner cast is applied to the parameter itself, the outer cast is applied when the CASE expression is evaluated to true*

Comment: Thanks a lot. The 2nd solution with explicit cast worked ! (the 1st still gave the error)

Comment: @WilfriedVisser - If the first one failed, you MAY have values exceeding the limit of INT.  Does firebird have a BIGINT variant that you can use?

Comment: Firebird indeed has a BIGINT type, but the fact the first one fails has to do with the fact that the CAST is applied to the parameter itself (see also my edit of my post) so it is evaluated at parse-time and not at execution time. By nesting the casts the inner one is evaluated at parse time, but the outer one is evaluated at execution time when the CASE condition is true.

Comment: I accept you answer. And I understand why the 2nd one works. B.t.w. I used an INTEGER this time (not BIGINT). Thanks a lot !